# I am trying to get code to convert epoch time (Ex. 1621690499.4047496) to unix hex timestamp (Ex.60a90883XXXXXXXX) using python

Tags: python, unix-timestamp, epoch

I tried below line of code, to convert but I need complete conversion (8 bytes of hex value Ex. 60a79ed81c256a2b, which gives accurate time (Nano seconds))

```
print (hex(int(time.time())))
```

0x60a90883  (4 bytes)

```
print (time.time())
```

1621690499.4047496

Comment: `time.time() * 10**9` & then convert?

Comment: >>> print (hex(int(time.time() * 10**9)))
0x168169842b288200
>>> print (time.time())
1621693357.2112238
>>> print (hex(int(time.time() * 10**0)))
0x60a913ad
>>> print (hex(int(time.time())))
0x60a913ad
>>>   <<No proper hex conversion>>>